# How to take certain elements from one container and insert a transform of those into another container?

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

I have a `vector<int*>` and I want to place all pointed at elements into a `vector<int>`.  All non-pointed at elements are set to `nullptr`.

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
vector<int> copy_valid_elements(vector<int*> piv)
{
 vector<int> result;
 result.reserve(piv.size());
 auto end_it = std::remove_if(piv.begin(), piv.end(), [](int* p) { return !p; });
 std::transform(piv.begin(), end_it, back_inserter(result), [](int* p) { return *p; });
 return result;
}
```

But that would require moving elements in the array unnecessarily.  I could do a for loop, but I was hoping there was an algorithm that's a cross between `std::copy_if` and `std::transform`.  Is there such a beast?

Comment: Why do you have a vector of *pointers*? Are they pointers to *single* values, or pointers to dynamically allocated arrays? If the first, why the pointers? If the latter, why not a vector of vectors?

Comment: The Standard Library isn't intended to contain every possible algorithm, rather a core set of examples - I have written `transform_if` myself before now, it's pretty easy. Sadly the current model doesn't easily support combining algorithms - the proposed ranges library goes some way to help with that. You may also consider a [`boost::filter_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/filter.html) feeding into `std::transform`.

Comment: if you don't need to use `algorithm`, it just `for(...){if(...)push_back(...)}`

Comment: @appleapple The point isn't that this is a particularly difficult problem to solve, but rather that it is very easy to solve *inelegantly* - using a named and well understood algorithm more clearly expresses intent than a `for` loop, and is less likely to be tweaked/added to later, making the behaviour slightly different and therefore less clear.

Comment: @BoBTFish I personally find `algorithm` pretty confusing. if it can give the easy use like `LINQ` I might change my mind. but as it is now, plain `range based for` (maybe inside a function with proper name) is a lot clear and more flexible for me.

Comment: @Adrian, I believe you get the example wrong and your result vector would have garbage at end.

Comment: You use case appears in the [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html) user manual as a motivating example.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, using a vector of pointers because the lifespan of the vector exceeds the lifespan of the integers that it will points to, and not all entries will be set, so I need a way to distinguish between set and not set.  Don't want to use `optional` as that would make the vector bigger than needed.  This is only a temporary vector to do some intermediate representation of a problem to get to the final solution.  In any case, this problem is just a vector of objects that is conditionally mapped to another vector of other objects.  My particular problem is not that relevant.

Comment: @appleapple, yes, I could have done that and in fact stated that I could have done so. The question wasn't if I could generate an algorithm, but if there was an algorithm or combination of algorithms that already existed that could do so.

Comment: @Adrian IMHO plain for (if possible) is always more clear. Since you don't have pair of iterator as input, I don't see the need to use generic `algorithm`. (and as my previous comment, you actually got the example code wrong when use it, the result vector would have zeros at end)

Comment: @appleapple, you're right, there was a bug, but not due to the algorithms I used, it was caused by the initial starting point of the vector and not using a back_inserter.  In any case, algorithms are, for the most part, easier to understand the intention of what is wanted and are battlefield tested.  This is why we have them in the first place and is why I am always trying to increase my understanding of what algorithms there are and how to use them.

Comment: @Adrian for `algorithm` I mean the `<algorithm>`. And no, if use plain `push_back` there would not have that mistake (or at least it's obvious). Just my opinion, though. And for this, `for(int* x : piv)if(x)result.push_back(*x);` is simply clean and explain what's going on pretty well.

Comment: @appleapple, in this one trivial instance, sure, but not in general. If there is a standard general algorithm, then it is better to use that, as they are standard and well understood.  They also explicitly decouple the implementation from the specialization of the algorithm, which is a good thing.

Comment: @Adrian They are standard, yes. they are well understood, well, hopefully. For example the `transform_if` in answer, it is not clear at all IMHO, especially the 2 lambda as parameter.

Comment: @appleapple yeah. I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. If it's not well understood, then it shouldn't have made it into the standard. If a single developer doesn't understand it when the rest do, then perhaps the one needs to take a step back an find another reference frame. I agree that c++ isn't always clear, esp to beginners, but there are patterns that are used on a fairly frequent basis, that make them easier to follow when one gets used to them. In terms of the `transform_if` ex, are you referring to the API or how it is read when used?

Comment: @Adrian I referring to *how it is read when used*. i.e. the intention of each lambda cannot be easily find out without look at function declaration. Besides if someone get it wrong, maybe no compiler error would be given.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a function template that applies an optional transformation, with two predicates: one for filtering and one for the actual mapping.

```
template <class InpIt, class OutIt, class Pred, class Fct>
OutIt transform_if(InpIt first, InpIt last, OutIt dest, Pred pred, Fct transform)
{
   while (first != last) {
      if (pred(*first))
         *dest++ = transform(*first);

      ++first;
   }

   return dest;
}
```

You can call it like this

```
int n1 = 1, n2 = 2, n3 = 3;

std::vector<int*> input{&n1, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &n2, &n3, nullptr};
std::vector<int> result;

transform_if(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), std::back_inserter(result),
    [](auto *i){ return i != nullptr; }, [](auto *i){ return *i; });
```

Another possibility is using a range library, as one of their main purposes is easy composition of algorithms. With Boost range:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

using namespace boost::adaptors;

/* Variable setup as above... */

boost::copy(input | filtered([](auto *i){ return i != nullptr; }) | indirected,
    std::back_inserter(result));
```

Comment: You need to dereference the `dest` iterator when you write to it.

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for writing an algorithm, but my question was not to make a new one, but to see if there was one that already existed.  The boost one is interesting and I'll look into that, but unfortunately, for the problem that I am trying to solve, I am not able to use boost.  Thanks again.

Comment: (Meta-answer): You should be comfortable writing your own algorithms. There's nothing magical about the ones in the standard library; they're just been given more "attention" than others. Writing your own algorithms is not rocket-science.  The one that @lubgr wrote for you does exactly what you asked for, and does it well. The only improvement that I can see is that it needs a `return dest;` at the end to return the (modified) output iterator.

Comment: @MarshallClow Thanks for the hint! I adjusted that.